# SIMD version check

Tags: c, gcc, simd

I am using Intel Core2Duo E4500 processor. It is supposed to have SSE3, SSSE3 facilities. But if I try to use them in programs it shows the following error "SSE3 instruction set not enabled"

Any ideas?

Comment: can you clarify a little bit, what is you program, have you access to the source ?  and if yes which compiler ?

Comment: ...and which compiler options?

Comment: I am writing c program using gcc4.4.1.

Comment: Please provide more information. Even an example . How are you "Using" the sse instructions(assembly, compiler intristics etc. ?) What compiler options do you use, who's issuing the error ? (Copy paste the command line you're using to compile whatever you're doing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) to check for available instruction sets.

If you're using Visual Studio, there's an option in `C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Enable Enhanced Instruction Set`.

Here's how to enable it in [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html).

From the above link:

```
-msse3
-mssse3
```

Comment: Surely the poster is trying to write a program that will choose at runtime whether to use SIMD instructions?  Using CPU-Z is fine for a human to examine their hardware, but useless for programmatic use.

Comment: @Edmund: The answer was accepted ; so I think it's safe to say that this is what the poster wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this gcc command line options:

```
-march=core2 -msse3
```

And probably is also a good idea to turn on sse optimizations for floating point operations:

```
-mfpmath=sse
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, have a look at the `flags` field of the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: cat /proc/cpuinfo gives SSSE3 but it does not show SSE3, but again for SSSE3 also it shows SSSE3 instruction set not enabled..

Answer (score 0):

If you compile on the same machine where you will be executing your code, with any recent gcc you should be able to use `-march=native` to take advantage of all your CPU features. It should tell you during compilation then, if you are using unsupported instructions in your `asm`.